# When doing POST of a json stringify object to MVC controller all booleans are false

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, post, stringify

I have a simple get controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic Get(UserPreferenceDto userPreference, bool onlyGlobal = false)
    { 
    }
```

and an AJAX query that posts to it:

```
var userPreference = /* some complex object */
        query({
            type: "POST",
            url: that.setting.host + "UserPreference/Get",
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: 'true' })
        }).done(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).fail(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

When I debug that, the userPreference is correct on the controller, but the onlyGlobal bool is always false.

I tried pretty much everything:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: 'true' })
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: true })
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: "TRUE" })
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: 1 })
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: '1' })
data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: "1" })
data: { userPreference: JSON.stringify(userPreference), onlyGlobal: true })
data: "?userPreference=" + JSON.stringify(userPreference)+"&onlyGlobal=true"
```

I am running out of things I can try to get that silly boolean to be passed onto the controller as "true". The complex object is correct no matter how much data I add to it.

Any ideas?

### UPDATE

I think what I am trying to do is infeasible. MVC can either figure out a list of primitive types or one complex object. 
It can't do both without providing a custom binder which is a shame because it seems relatively straightforward. If someone knows of a workaround, or can provide a simple binder that can handle it, please go ahead and I'll accept your answer

Comment: why this parameter declaration?- `bool onlyGlobal = false`

Comment: that's just the optional default declaration, so someone can call the controller method by only passing one parameter.

Comment: you should make it optional as- `bool? onlyGlobal`

Comment: @Manoz that is not as issue, Op is using optional param

Comment: no because bool? makes it nullable. It's not the same. Using default values you can declare the method with only one parameter: Get(userPreference). 

Anyway I don't think the default makes any difference because I have the same problem if I just declare bool onlyGlobal

Comment: @Nick why are you putting it in quotes, you can directly pass ``true``

Comment: Ehsan, did you see the list of alternatives I tried? Makes no difference

Comment: Have you tried just `data: { onlyGlobal: true },` to see if the other parameter may be an issue.

Comment: Yes that works. I think what I am trying to do is infeasible. MVC can either figure out a list of primitive types or one complex object. It can't do both without providing a custom binder.. such a shame because it seems such a simple thing

Comment: Yes, of course it can. The reason I suggested you try that is because there is something wrong with `data: JSON.stringify({ userPreference: userPreference, onlyGlobal: 'true' })` - it should not be able to bind to `UserPreferenceDto` so I'm not sure how you construct `userPreference` on the client side to make this work as you claim. Can you post the code for the model and for generating `userPreference`

Comment: why are u passing 'true' as string, while the action method is expecting boolean. not sure if that is related, but just found it weird

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i don't know what's wrong with this but in my case i changed the approach and posted the data like 
For Partial Views

```
<script>function GetPostalAddress() {
var PostalAddress = {};
PostalAddress.CountryID = _("CountryID");
PostalAddress.CityID = _("CityID");
PostalAddress.ProvinceID = _("ProvinceID");
PostalAddress.ZipCode = _("ZipCode");
PostalAddress.StreetAddress = _("StreetAddress");
return PostalAddress;
}</script>
```

For Forms using those partial views
    you wil also include ajax function
Hope its not too late and helps.